# EF Core .Include is losing records when the related table has records physically deleted

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

**EDIT:** To add some clarifying information.

The Payment.cs has this FK property

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(LocationId))]
public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
```

This is the database context for Payments in a context called cpContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Payments>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PaymentId)
                .IsClustered(false);

            ... other properties ...

            entity.Property(e => e.TzgRecordId).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.Utc).HasColumnType("datetime");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceStatuses>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InvoiceStatus);

            entity.ToTable("InvoiceStatus", "enum");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceStatus).HasColumnName("InvoiceStatus");

            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentStatuses>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Status);

            entity.ToTable("PaymentStatus", "enum");

            entity.Property(e => e.Status).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        //Have to include these for the joins across databases to display the value instead of ID
        modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceTypes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceType);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Devices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organizations>(entity =>
        {
            //entity.ToTable("Organizations", "[opkCore].dbo");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrgUnits>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgUnitId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Locations>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.LocationId)
                .HasName("PK_Location");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryModes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InventoryMode);
        });
```

Locations.cs has this and many other fields, but this is the relevant stuff:

```
[Key]
public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
```

This in the database context for Location (in a different context called dataContext.cs), and of course a lot of other fields of data:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Locations>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.LocationId)
                .HasName("PK_Location");

            ... other properties ...

            entity.Property(e => e.ValidationButtonCaption)
                .HasMaxLength(10)
                .HasComment("Name of the validation button.");
        });

        //Have to include these for the joins across databases to display the value instead of ID
        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceStatuses>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InvoiceStatus);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentStatuses>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Status);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Payments>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PaymentId)
                .IsClustered(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceTypes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceType);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Devices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceId);
        });


        modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryModes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InventoryMode);

            entity.Property(e => e.InventoryMode).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });
```

---

**ORIGINAL:** How can I convert this to return the records even if the Location record is missing in the Locations table? Everything works great except that sometimes there is no record in the Location table that matches the LocationId on the Payment record. The Location record has since been deleted. Removing the .Include returns everything, but then of course the columns of Location data that I want to display are all empty when there is a Location record to join to.

```
var listForView = payments.AsNoTracking()
.Include(payments => payments.PaymentStatuses)
.Include(payments => payments.InvoiceStatuses)
.Include(payments => payments.Organizations)
.Include(payments => payments.Locations);
```

My base query looks like this, but there are a bunch of .Where as I filter the table based on certain criteria.

```
                payments = from pmts in _context.Payments
                       select pmts;
```

I have tried a couple solutions such as doing the join a different way than using .Include, but they are making it so I don't get any of the data on the rows that have the data to join to. Could someone point me in the right direction for how to do a join that will let me display related data when it is there, but not completely remove the record from the data set when the data is not there? If those columns are blank that is fine (the data isn't there), but I don't want to be missing records entirely.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by " Location data that has a locationId that does not exist" ?

Comment: I will edit my question to clarify. I mean that there is no record in the Location table that matches the LocationId on the Payment record. The Location record has since been deleted. The FK relationship has been broken.

Comment: How is relation between `Location` and `Payment` is set up?

Comment: I have added a bunch more content to the question. Thank you for your interest in helping. It means a lot.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. I figured out what my problem is and it was not code. The records actually do exist in the database. I just didn't copy them over when I made my development environment. What a phenomenal waste of time for a stupid reason.

Comment: If you still would like to answer that would be good. I would at least learn how to handle it if I did run into that situation where related records are deleted.

Comment: Glad that you have figured it out! Does it work now if records are deleted?

Comment: Also i would say that `[ForeignKey(nameof(LocationId))]` on `LocationId` looks wrong to me. It should be looking like `[ForeignKey(nameof(Location))]` or be applied to navigation property itself. Also it should be `Guid?` if relation is not mandatory.